# Android EditText app freezes on calling clear inside TextWatcher

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, freeze, android-textinputedittext

My app is freezing on calling clear onTextChanged TextWatcher

Following is my code

```
        materialEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(s.toString().equals("$")){
                materialEditText.getText().clear();
         
            }
            else if(!s.toString().contains("$")){
                materialEditText.setText("$"+s);
                Selection.setSelection(materialEditText.getText(), materialEditText.getText().length());

            }
        }
```

Following line is causing freeze how to fix this?

```
 materialEditText.getText().clear();
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, I guess it is going inside an infinite loop because of the statement you kept in `onTextChanged` i.e `materialEditText.setText("$"+s);`

Comment: oh yes thanks fixed it. Can you post this as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `setText()` in `onTextChanged()` of an `editText` will cause infinite loop. You need to do a workaround to `setText()` by either using flag or some any other means. Update text only if not updated. So that it don't go into infinite loop